# Is it possible to restrict the number of clicks on email?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-studio

We would like to send out the email with the link which will give subscribers the gift codes. We would like them to click only once to get the gift code. Is it possible to restrict the number of clicks?

Answer (score 1):

Once an email is in the user's inbox, there's nothing you can do to change/restrict the user from clicking the link.

What you can do is to restrict what happens when the user comes to the link the second/multiple times. You need to build a flag that gets set the very first time the user visits the page. On every subsequent visit, check if the flag is set, in which case give a standard message - "The gift code has already been redeemed" or something similar.

If you are stuck at a specific place, let us know the exact problem statement and we can help you find a solution.